# Multiple hovers and variables in one hover function

Tags: javascript, variables, hover, jquery-hover

I'd like to be able to type in a CSS selector, give it a title and description. Basically, it is a helper tooltip, so when you hover over something, it displays in the sidebar.

How can I simplify this? I might have 50 or more these, and my code would be super redundant. I've tried creating variables, however, I get stuck on the hover class since it can be anything.

They all do the same thing, just different title, description and selector class.

```
    $('.class1').hover(
      function () {
          $('.my-why').hide();
          $('.sidebar').append('<div class="helpertip">' +
          '<h5><a style="color:#fff;">Title #1</a></h5>' +
          '<p id="myWhy">Description #1</p>' +
          '</div>');

      }, function () {
          $('.my-why').show();
          $('.helpertip').remove();
      }
    );

    $('.class2').hover(
      function () {
          $('.my-why').hide();
          $('.sidebar').append('<div class="helpertip">' +
          '<h5><a style="color:#fff;">Title #2</a></h5>' +
          '<p id="myWhy">Description #2</p>' +
          '</div>');

      }, function () {
          $('.my-why').show();
          $('.helpertip').remove();
      }
    );

    $('.class3').hover(
      function () {
          $('.my-why').hide();
          $('.sidebar').append('<div class="helpertip">' +
          '<h5><a style="color:#fff;">Title #3</a></h5>' +
          '<p id="myWhy">Description #3</p>' +
          '</div>');

      }, function () {
          $('.my-why').show();
          $('.helpertip').remove();
      }
    );
```

I did have this, can't figure out how to have multiple variables...

```
var hclass = 
var htitle =
var hdescription = 

$(hclass).hover(
      function () {
          $('.my-why').hide();
          $('.sidebar').append('<div class="helpertip">' +
          '<h5><a style="color:#fff;">' + htitle + '</a></h5>' +
          '<p id="myWhy">' + hdescription + '</p>' +
          '</div>');

      }, function () {
          $('.my-why').show();
          $('.helpertip').remove();
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how about using data attributes on the containing elements? If they have data-title and data-description, containing all the relevant information, then you can have a single function like this for all of them:

```
$("div.classes").hover(function () {
  var myTitle = $(this).data("title");
  var myDescription = $(this).data("description");

      $('.my-why').hide();
      $('.sidebar').append('<div class="helpertip">' +
      '<h5><a style="color:#fff;">'+myTitle+'</a></h5>' +
      '<p id="myWhy">'+myDescription'+</p>' +
      '</div>');

  }, function () {
      $('.my-why').show();
      $('.helpertip').remove();
  }
);
```

Of course, you'd have to give ALL the relevant elements a convenient selector class.

But if, as you say, you'd prefer to avoid stuffing the HTML with unneccessary clutter (and why wouldn't you? Better to let the code be separate from the view), consider this:

```
var myCollection = [{
  name: 'class1',
  title: 'Title 1',
  description: 'Lorem Ipsum'
}, {
  name: 'class2',
  title: 'Title 2',
  description: 'Dolor Sit Amet'
}, {
  name: 'class3',
  title: 'Title 3',
  description: 'Vivamus magna justo'
}, {
  name: 'class4',
  title: 'Title 4',
  description: 'Your preferred random description here...'
}];
// I'm going to iterate over my collection of
// objects and simply create a hover for each  one.
$.each(myCollection, function(index, item){
  // this.class refers to the class variable in the current
  //  object of the iterated collection.
  $(this.class).hover(function () {    
    $('.my-why').hide();
    $('.sidebar').append('<div class="helpertip">' +
      '<h5><a style="color:#fff;">'+ this.title +'</a></h5>' +
      '<p id="myWhy">'+ this.description +'</p>' +
      '</div>');
    }, function () {
      $('.my-why').show();
      $('.helpertip').remove();
  });
})
```

With this, I've created a collection that I can iterate over, and simply call the hover on each one in turn. within the $.each(), I can refer to this to get the current object, and this.title or this.description to get my relevant data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this as my second option, but I'd prefer to keep it in one place and not to add stuff to the HTML.

Comment: I've amended the code. Take a look at the second option, this may be more what you're looking for. By having all the data in a collection, I'm not creating a huge collection of variables. By iterating over that collection, I can create the same behaviours. Hope this helps!

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: glad it helped.